# Sum of closed subsets with at least one compact is also closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a linear topological space. If $A$ and $B$ are two closed subsets of $X$, and at least one of them is compact, prove that $A+B$ is also closed.

As I'm taking my first steps in the field of functional analysis, I've come across this problem. Even though I'm aware of what each term refers to, I'm not sure how to put them together. I was thinking by starting with supposing that $x \notin A+B$ and eventually reach a contradiction. Some clarifications would be more than welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost no, I do not.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose without loss of generality that $A$ is compact, and suppose that $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A+B)$; we want to show that $x\in A+B$. Since $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A+B)$, there are nets $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle$ in $A$ and $\langle b_i:i\in I\rangle$ in $B$ such that the net $\langle a_i+b_i:i\in I\rangle$ converges to $x$. Since $A$ is compact, the net $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle$ has a subnet $\langle a_j:j\in J\rangle$ converging to some $a\in A$.

- Show that $\langle a+b_j:j\in J\rangle$ converges to $x$.
- Use the fact that $B$ is closed to conclude that $x\in A+B$.

If $X$ is first countable, and in particular if $X$ is normed, you can replace nets and subnets with sequences and subsequences.

Comment: Are you assuming that the space is first-countable? I've forgotten most of topology and am not sure whether this is necessary. With some search I found the name [Fréchet–Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space), but I don't know whether every linear topological space is Fréchet–Urysohn. I think it would be the case if the topology is induced by a norm, but not all linear topological spaces are normed, right?

Comment: @WhatsUp: I actually misread it as specifying a normed linear space. The idea still works in general if I replace the sequence by nets.